# Flutter custom platform-specific code official example error (Android)

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, dart

I tried to implement Android-specific code into my Flutter app.
I tried to implement official example but the example made an error.

If you have any idea, Please share me.

Android Kotlin code:

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

import android.content.Context
import android.content.ContextWrapper
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.IntentFilter
import android.os.BatteryManager
import android.os.Build.VERSION
import android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES


class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
  private val CHANNEL = "my_string/battery"

  override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    super.configureFlutterEngine(flutterEngine)
        MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler {
      // This method is invoked on the main thread.
      call, result ->
      if (call.method == "getBatteryLevel") {
        val batteryLevel = getBatteryLevel()

        if (batteryLevel != -1) {
          result.success(batteryLevel)
        } else {
          result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Battery level not available.", null)
        }
      } else {
        result.notImplemented()
      }
    }

  }

    private fun getBatteryLevel(): Int {
    val batteryLevel: Int
    if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
      val batteryManager = getSystemService(Context.BATTERY_SERVICE) as BatteryManager
      batteryLevel = batteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY)
    } else {
      val intent = ContextWrapper(applicationContext).registerReceiver(null, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED))
      batteryLevel = intent!!.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1) * 100 / intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1)
    }

    return batteryLevel
  }

}
```

Flutter Dart code:

```
Future<void> getBatteryLevel() async {
    var platform = MethodChannel('my_string/battery');
    String batteryLevel;
    try {
      int batteryLevel = await platform.invokeMethod('getBatteryLevel');
      // batteryLevel = 'Battery level at $result % .';
      print(batteryLevel);
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      batteryLevel = "Failed to get battery level: '${e.message}'.";
    }
  }
```

Error:

```
E/flutter (21390): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getBatteryLevel on channel my_string/battery)
E/flutter (21390): #0      MethodChannel._invokeMethod
platform_channel.dart:313
E/flutter (21390): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (21390): #1      PreferencePageViewModel.studyplusLogIn
preference_page_view_model.dart:904
E/flutter (21390): <asynchronous suspension>
```

For iOS, the official example worked but it doesn't work for Android.

Comment: Try executing 'Flutter clean' and then running the app again.

Comment: After clean .. if still it doesn't work the use Pigeon package. It generates typeSafe platform specific code.
 https://pub.dev/packages/pigeon

Comment: I tried to run the same code locally and it seems to print the current battery level on my physical Android device -- API 33.

Answer (score 0):

I finally soleved this error!
AndroidManifest.xml was cause of problem.
I replaced <activity> in my AndroidManifest.xml with that of Flutter initial example.

【This code made an error】

```
<activity
        android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:exported="true">
```

【I changed it to this】

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
```